# Confusing transitive dependency behavior with xml-apis

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

In my project I depend on several external libraries that depend on various versions of `xml-apis`. If I use `maven-enforcer-plugin` [to fail if there are version conflicts](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) my build fails.

Before I started, printing the classpath of my running app gives `xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01`

When I enable `maven-enforcer-plugin` I get this, which is expected

```
Dependency convergence error for xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04 paths to dependency are:

+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.bbraile:utd:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-xalan:xalan:2.7.2
      +-xalan:serializer:2.7.2
        +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
and
+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.bbraile:utd:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
and
+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.bbraile:utd:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0
      +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
and
+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.io7m.xom:xom:1.2.10
    +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03
and
+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
    +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:1.7
      +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:1.7
        +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
and
+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
    +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:1.7
      +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:1.7
        +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
and
+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
    +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:1.7
      +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:1.7
        +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
and
+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
    +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:1.7
      +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
and
+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
    +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:1.7
      +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
and
+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
    +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:1.7
      +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
and
+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
    +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:1.7
      +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
and
+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
    +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:1.7
      +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
and
+-org.bbraile:bbraile:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
    +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
```

To fix this based on what I've read I should add this to my POM

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And re-run my program again. It passes `maven-enforcer-plugin` checks but my classpath says now I'm running `xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2`. How did the version number get older? Why is my version getting ignored?

Adding this to my POM, with or without the `<version>` tag has no effect

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Consulting `dependency:tree -Dverbose=true -Dincludes=xml-apis` gives below, which implies `2.0.2`

```
org.bbraile:bbraile:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
+- org.bbraile:utd:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile
|  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile
|  |     \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for conflict with 1.0.b2)
|  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
|     \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for duplicate)
+- com.io7m.xom:xom:jar:1.2.10:compile
|  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for duplicate)
+- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:jar:1.7:compile
|  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:jar:1.7:compile
|  |  |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
|  |  |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
|  |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.7:compile
|  |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.7:compile
|  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.7:compile
|  |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:jar:1.7:compile
|  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile - version managed from 1.0.b2; omitted for duplicate)
|  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
\- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2:compile
```

Why is my explicit version in dependencyManagment being ignored? Why did setting that reduce the version on my classpath? How can I pass `maven-enforcer-plugin` with the most recent `xml-apis` version?

Comment: How exactly are you checking which version is on your classpath?

Comment: @TavianBarnes Running with `exec:exec` and printing System.getProperty("java.class.path"). The maven jar's have the version number in them

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Turns out this isn't a maven problem, this is a xml-api's problem. As of today this is how `xml-apis:xml-apis` looks in Maven Central

[image: Very confusing xml-apis versions]

If you look carefully 2.0.2 isn't the latest release, 1.4.01 is! While everybody else and their IDEs considers 2 to be greater than 1, xml-apis goes backwards.

This is extremely confusing and non-obvious, so hopefully someone finds this useful.

Comment: If you look at the POM files for both 2.0.0 and 2.0.2, they are "relocated" to version 1.0.b2
This is a giant mess and confuses a lot of build tools and scripts.

<distributionManagement><relocation><groupId>xml-apis</groupId><artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId><version>1.0.b2</version></relocation></distributionManagement>